# Batch file to list all txt files with a certain filename and certain content on windows server 2008

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm looking for a batch file that allows me to search for files, created within a certain timeframe (e.g. 2013-01-01 till 2013-01-20), with a specific name pattern (e.g. *foo.xml) that contain a certain string (e.g. "mySearchString").

I tried some stuff using the forfiles but it does not allow me to set a date period - it only allows me to search for files before or after a certain date.

Anybody out there to help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Kai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `set "searchterm=apple"` to your search term

Alter these line to the dates you need
`set oldest=2006-06-01`
`set newest=2006-12-31`

Change the filespec in this line: `"c:\files\*.txt"`

```
@echo off
:: based upon code by Todd Vargo 2007
setlocal

set "searchterm=apple"

:: Set date range below in yyyy-mm-dd format or your local format.
set oldest=2006-06-01
set newest=2006-12-31
::  =================
set tmp1="%temp%.\dir.out"

::  Set any legal filespec desired below.
dir "c:\files\*.txt" /a-d/s/b >%tmp1%
::  ==================

set vbs="%temp%.\tmp.vbs"
type nul>%vbs%
call :vbs echo >>%vbs%
cscript /nologo %vbs% >"%temp%\filelist.tmp"
del %vbs%
del %tmp1%

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%temp%\filelist.tmp") do (
findstr /i /c:"%searchterm%" "%%a" >nul && echo found "%searchterm%" in "%%a"
)
del "%temp%\filelist.tmp" 2>nul
pause
goto :eof

:vbs
%1 d1 = #%oldest%#
%1 d2 = #%newest%#
%1 Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
%1 'Wscript.Echo DateDiff("d", d1, d2)
%1 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
%1 Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(%tmp1%, ForReading)
%1 count = 0
%1 Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
%1   s = f.ReadLine
%1   Set f1 = fso.GetFile(s)
%1   If d1 ^< DateValue(f1.DateCreated) and _
%1     DateValue(f1.DateCreated) ^< d2 Then
%1     Wscript.Echo f1.Path
%1     count = count + 1
%1   End If
%1 Loop
%1 ' Wscript.Echo "     Total Files Listed:", count
```

Comment: works ;-) - the only change I did was changing
    `d1 ^< DateValue(f1.DateCreated)` and `DateValue(f1.DateCreated) ^< d2` to `d1 ^<= DateValue(f1.DateCreated)` and `DateValue(f1.DateCreated) ^<= d2`